# Running commands in background from TCL script and formatting output

Tags: shell, redirect, background, tcl

I have a tcl script which runs multiple shell commands serially.

Something like this:

abc.tcl

```
command 1
command 2 
command 3
...
command n
```

This script prints the outputs of these commands into a text file in the following format:

```
### ### ### ### ### ###
Command name
### ### ### ### ### ###

Command Output

### ### ### ### ### ##
```

I was trying to get the script to run faster but making the shell commands run in parallel instead of serially. By pushing them to the background (command a &). But I'm at a loss how to retain the formatting of my output text file as was the case before.

When I push the commands in to background I'm forced to append their outputs into a temporary file, but these files just have the output of the commands in a dump together. It's difficult to differentiate between the different outputs.

Is there someway I can redirect the output of each command running in the background to an individual temp file (maybe the name of the temp file can have the process id of the background running process). And once all commands have run, I can cat the outputs together in to the proper format? Any ideas/suggestions on how I can accomplish this.

Comment: As an alternative, maybe I could run the shell commands in background and push them to individual temp files, and get notified once they're done executing and then cat them in to the main file.

I'm worried of getting in to a multiple processes writing into a same file at same time situation here, don't want the output file to go corrupt.

And don't really know how to signal that the background processes are done running from within the tcl script.

Comment: You can do it with `fileevent`; reader pipes become readable when they cease to have a far end. (Writers block…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the commands don't have state that depends on each other, you can parallelize them. There are many ways to do this, but one of the easier is to use the thread package's [thread pooling](http://tcl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tcl/thread/doc/html/tpool.html) (which requires a threaded Tcl, the norm on many platform nowadays):

```
package require Thread

set pool [tpool::create -maxworkers 4]
# The list of *scripts* to evaluate
set tasks {
    {command 1}
    {command 2}
    ...
    {command n}
}

# Post the work items (scripts to run)
foreach task $tasks {
    lappend jobs [tpool::post $pool $task]
}

# Wait for all the jobs to finish
for {set running $jobs} {[llength $running]} {} {
    tpool::wait $pool $running running
}

# Get the results; you might want a different way to print the results...
foreach task $tasks job $jobs {
    set jobResult [tpool::get $pool $job]
    puts "TASK: $task"
    puts "RESULT: $jobResult"
}
```

The main tweakable is the size of the thread pool, which defaults to a limit of 4. (Set it via the `-maxworkers` option to `tpool::create` which I've listed explicitly above.) The best value to choose depends on how many CPU cores you've got and how much CPU load each task generates on average; you'll need to measure and tune…

You can also use the `-initcmd` option to pre-load each worker thread in the pool with a script of your choice. That's a good place to put your `package require` calls. The workers are all *completely* independent of each other and of the master thread; they do not share state. You'd get the same model if you ran each piece of code in a separate process (but then you'd end up writing more code to do the coordinating).

---

[EDIT]: Here's a version that will work with Tcl 8.4 and which uses subprocesses instead.

```
namespace eval background {}
proc background::task {script callback} {
    set f [open |[list [info nameofexecutable]] "r+"]
    fconfigure $f -buffering line
    puts $f [list set script $script]
    puts $f {fconfigure stdout -buffering line}
    puts $f {puts [list [catch $script msg] $msg]; exit}
    fileevent $f readable [list background::handle $f $script $callback]
}
proc background::handle {f script callback} {
    foreach {code msg} [read $f] break
    catch {close $f}
    uplevel "#0" $callback [list $script $code $msg]
}

proc accumulate {script code msg} {
    puts "#### COMMANDS\n$script"
    puts "#### CODE\n$code"
    puts "#### RESULT\n$msg"

    # Some simple code to collect the results
    if {[llength [lappend ::accumulator $msg]] == 3} {
        set ::done yes
    }
}
foreach task {
    {after 1000;subst hi1}
    {after 2000;subst hi2}
    {after 3000;subst hi3}
} {
    background::task $task accumulate
}
puts "WAITING FOR TASKS..."
vwait done
```

Notes: the tasks are Tcl commands that produce a result, but they *must not* print the result out; the fabric code (in `background::task`) handles that. These are subprocesses; they share nothing with one another, so anything you want them to do or be configured with must be sent as part of the task. A more sophisticated version could keep a hot pool of subprocesses around and in general work very much like a thread pool (subject to the subtle differences due to being in a subprocess and not a thread) but that was more code than I wanted to write here.

Result codes (i.e., exception codes) are 0 for “ok”, 1 for “error”, and other values in less common cases. They're exactly the values documented on the [Tcl 8.6 `catch` manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/catch.htm); it's up to you to interpret them correctly. (I suppose I should also add code to make the `::errorInfo` and `::errorCode` variable contents be reported back in the case of an error, but that makes the code rather more complex…)

Comment: FWIW, the thread package should ship with a Tcl 8.6 installation (since at least 8.6b2) but there was a slip-up in the documentation build which means that the thread docs didn't go live on the www.tcl.tk website.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Thread pooling seems to be the elegant way of doing this. Unfortunately I'm running Tcl 8.4 right now, and no threads package. Are there other methods to accomplish something similar?

Comment: @egorulz Sure, you can do it with subprocesses. It'll take me a bit to research the details…